# Mongodb python google app engine

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, google-app-engine

Hi I am trying to run mongodb on google app engine but I am stuck. I am using pymongo library and I have added it to my lib folder. When I run the app, it says some module is missing. I add this module in the lib folder and after that another module is missing.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient()
db = client.newsmapusers
```

Answer (score 0):

These problem happen in the google app engine.Sometimes when you add a missing module it might show another module is missing'error so you have to put all the missing modules into the lib folder until the problem solves.

Answer (score 0):

in the root directory of your project add the file `appengine_config.py`.  In that file you need to add the following:

`from google.appengine.ext import vendor
vendor.add('lib')`

To make sure you get all dependencies of the lib you are using I would use `pip` like this: `pip install -U -t ./lib -r ./requirements.txt` with a file that contains all of your dependencies.

See "[Using Third Party Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27)" docs for more info

(Also, FWIW, why Mongo and not [Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/getting-started/storing-data-datastore)?)